# O quinto dos infernos

Tags: uso-de-palavras, expressões, português-europeu

No Brasil essa expressão é usada como palavrão, exemplo:

> Vá para o quinto dos infernos

Nos dá a entender que é o pior lugar do inferno.

O [Dicionário Informal](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/quinto+dos+infernos/) diz que *o termo tem sua origem no período colonial do Brasil e diz respeito à cobrança de impostos por Império Português. O quinto correspondia a 20% da produção de ouro da colônia. Afirma-se que o termo era dirigido aos cobradores de impostos, que ao exigir o quinto ouviam algo como "Vá buscar o quinto nos infernos!"*

Hoje pagamos muito mais impostos...

Essa expressão é empregada em Portugal e outros países?

Comment: Denis, encontrei um artigo de 1931 que discute várias hipóteses acerca da origem da expressão, incluindo a da aversão ao imposto. Acrescentei um resumo das principais ideias na resposta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As expressões ***quinto dos infernos, quintos dos infernos*** ou, a que parece ser a original, ***quintos infernos***, foram em Portugal comuns no passado, mas são hoje relativamente raras. Eu não as conhecia, e não vêm no Dicionário da Academia de Ciências de Lisboa (2001). Mas procurando na net encontram-se em Portugal, exemplos recentes de uso. Parece que a expressão foi caindo no esquecimento, mas há obviamente algumas pessoas que ainda a conhecem. No passado parece ter sido o contrário: até ao princípio do século XX encontro exemplos frequentes em autores portugueses mas não em brasileiros. Presentemente também se encontram exemplos de uso nos países lusófonos africanos.

Até há pouco tempo, *quinto* era raro; *quintos* é que era comum e é a variante que vem nos dicionários ([Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/quinto), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?id=qOGl8), [Priberam](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/quinto), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/quinto)). *Quinto* ou *quintos dos infernos* aparece simplesmente no sentido de ‘inferno’, especialmente em expressões do tipo *ir* ou *mandar para os quintos do inferno*, e no sentido de ‘lugar remoto’. Eis alguns exemplos, com negrito meu em todas as citações:

> quem **despachou o fulano para o quinto dos infernos**, foi um indivíduo ao serviço da PIDE
> [(Blog História Maximus, Portugal, 2016.)](http://historiamaximus.blogspot.pt/2016/05/aeroporto-general-coca-cola.html)

> O principal problema do Piódão é que fica longe de tudo. Para quem não conhece, fica no meio do nada: **ali para os lados dos quintos dos infernos**, entre o cu de Judas e onde o Diabo perdeu as botas.
> [(Blog top maquina, Portugal, 2016.)](http://topmaquina.blogs.sapo.pt/rescaldo-iv-inatel-piodao-trail-running-49349)

> "necessário e urgente" que esta sua maldita ditadura **baixe aos quintos dos infernos** duma vez por todas!
> [(Klub-K, Anglola, 2017.)](http://www.club-k.net/%7Eclubknet/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=27104:chattam-house-joao-lourenco-vai-desiludir-os-que-esperam-mudanca-politica-rapida-ou-radical&catid=23:politica&lang=pt&Itemid=1123)

> Queremos justiça para os que foram perseguidos. todos do paigc/cv deviam **morrer nos quintos dos infernos**.
> [(Expresso das Ilhas, Cabo Verde, 2014.)](http://www.expressodasilhas.sapo.cv/politica/item/42436-pm-vai-condecorar-membros-do-primeiro-governo/42436-pm-vai-condecorar-membros-do-primeiro-governo?start=10)

> Ela mais os todos corruptos que a apoiam - doadores engajados, maçonarias, opus dei, seitas várias, carteis de droga, mafias, operadores de tráfico humano, animal e florestal, ladrões de gravata, **escumalha do mais fundo dos quintos dos infernos**,...lixo abjecto.
> [(Blog Moçambique para todos, 2013.)](http://macua.blogs.com/moambique_para_todos/2013/04/benilde-nhalivilo-renuncia-%C3%A0-candidatura-a-membro-da-cne.html)

O dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) regista estas aceções todas e explica que existe simplesmente *quintos* (sem *dos infernos*), mas que o mais habitual é *quintos* vir intensificado com *dos infernos*:

> **quinto** […] □ *quintos s.m.pl. imformal* **7** mesmo que *INFERNO* (‘lugar de almas pecadoras’) **8** lugar muito distante ou desconhecido <*andar pelos quintos*> <*correr os quintos*> ◊ **ir para os quintos 1** ir para lugar longínquo **2** *pej.* deixar de viver; morrer **3** reduzir-se a nada; sumir **4** não ter êxito; gorar • **mandar para os quintos** *informal* 1** mandar para um lugar remoto, para que desapareça **2** tirar a vida a; matar **3** proferir impropérios […] GRAM/USO as locuções *ir para os quintos* e *mandar para os quintos* vêm geralmente seguidas da expressão intensificadora *dos infernos* […]

### Sobre a Origem

A explicação da origem da expressão citada na pergunta é quase de certeza uma invenção tardia. É essa a opinião de [Mário Eduardo Viaro da USP (*Estudos Etimológicos do Português no Passado e no Presente*, 2008)](http://www.usp.br/gmhp/publ/ViaBH.pdf) e a minha também: como de costume, a net está cheia de explicações sobre a origem, mas ninguém apresenta indícios documentais, nem parecem estar a par da história da expressão.

Há uma, a expressão que se encontra mais cedo no registo escrito é *quintos infernos* e não *dos infernos*; ou seja um lugar que é o ‘inferno nº 5’, o que não parece ter qualquer relação com impostos. *Quintos infernos* aparece logo em [1736](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PmteAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA130&dq=%22quintos%20infernos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtsILH37_TAhUFiRoKHa_yBBM4MhDoAQi7ATAW#v=onepage&q=%22quintos%20infernos%22&f=false) e [1738](https://books.google.pt/books?id=PmteAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA458&dq=%22que%20eftava%20nos%20quintos%20infernos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjp_4Pfw8DTAhUMORoKHcsJBxMQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22que%20eftava%20nos%20quintos%20infernos%22&f=false), em duas óperas de António José da Silva, e ainda [neste livro de 1748](https://books.google.pt/books?id=BiEBAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA15&dq=%22quintos%20infernos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtsILH37_TAhUFiRoKHa_yBBM4MhDoAQi0ATAV#v=onepage&q=%22quintos%20infernos%22&f=false), nesta [coleção de expressões populares de 1759](http://purl.pt/29106/3/#/158-159) e [nesta gramática de 1768](https://books.google.pt/books?id=U7oGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA244&dq=%22quintos%20infernos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif3OOr5b_TAhXCSRoKHQZ0BBAQ6AEI8AIwMQ#v=onepage&q=%22quintos%20infernos%22&f=false). Só encontrei *quintos dos infernos* a partir de [1829](https://books.google.pt/books?id=OYgAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA164&dq=%22quintos%20dos%20infernos%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix_57HqsDTAhVGahoKHS8jAw84MhDoAQiFATAP#v=onepage&q=%22quintos%20dos%20infernos%22&f=false), e mesmo assim com muito menos frequência que *quintos infernos* ao longo de todo o século XIX. No espanhol existe também [*el quinto infierno* e *los quintos infiernos* (‘lugar remoto’, ERA)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LWWgIMp), mas não *quintos de los infiernos*.

Depois, a expressão ocorre muito cedo em Portugal. Aliás, até meados do século XX só encontro *quintos (dos) infernos* em autores portugueses. O descontentamento com o imposto no Brasil não explica facilmente o aparecimento tão cedo da expressão em Portugal. O que não é implausível, é que existindo já a expressão *quintos infernos*, perante um imposto odioso chamado *quinto*, se passasse apelidá-lo de *quintos dos infernos*.

O Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) apresenta uma hipótese do filólogo brasileiro Antenor Nascentes relacionada com o imposto que já explicaria o surgimento da expressão em Portugal; mas continua a esbarrar no problema de a expressão original parecer ser *quintos infernos*:

> ETIMOLOGIA […] no caso da expressão *ir* ou *mandar para os quintos*, provavelmente do sentido *ir na nau dos quintos* ‘ir degredado para o Brasil’ (a *nau dos quintos* era a que levava à metrópole o imposto de 20% sobre os metais preciosos que davam entrada nos portos espanhóis e portugueses; por isso, *ir para os quintos* significava ser banido para esse lugar desconhecido, remoto, que era o Brasil e a América do Sul, nas eras coloniais, anota Antenor Nascentes).

Entretanto descobri um artigo na [*Revista Lusitana* (vol. 29, 1931, p. 134-7)](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/conhecer/biblioteca-digital-camoes/etnologia-etnografia-tradicoes.html?limit=20&limitstart=20) que discute estas e outras hipóteses. O autor rejeita a explicação baseada na aversão ao imposto, precisamente por ela não explicar a popularidade da expressão em Portugal. Mais ainda, ele sugere que o “direito senhorial dos quintos” foi assim chamado em 1750 (substituindo a “capitação das minas”); a expressão já antes estava em uso em Portugal. Outra hipótese registada é que *quintos* se refira à povoação dos [Quintos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintos) no Alentejo, sul de Portugal. Outrora estes Quintos ficavam no extremo do país, e admite-se que se degredassem para lá criminosos, daí, segundo esta tese, a expressão *mandar para os quintos*. O pessoa da zona, ao tempo do artigo, acreditavam que era esta a origem da expressão. Ainda outra hipótese, é que a expressão tenha origem nos *quintos*, uma antiga punição que consistia em *quintar*, ou seja castigar uma em cada cinco pessoas quando se desconhecia o responsável.

Comment: Eu achava – sem nenhuma evidência que sustente essa ideia – que tinha a ver com os círculos do Inferno de Dante. Encontrou alguma referência a isso na sua pesquisa?

Comment: @bfavaretto, essa tem a vantagem de se aplicar a *quintos infernos*, que se encontra mais cedo. Essa hipótese já foi avançada por alguns, e é discutida, e achada pouco provável, [neste artigo do Cáudio Moreno](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/06/o-quinto-dos-infernos-o-retorno/) e também no artigo do Mário Viaro que eu linko na resposta. O Cláudio Moreno também fala dos sete infernos do Islão. Entre uma e  outra eu preferiria a última, que é compatível com origem popular; a *Divida Comédia* não devia ser conhecida por muita gente. >>

Comment: >> Mas não há nada de especial no quinto círculo do Dante ou no quinto inferno do Islão. Depois ainda há o plural...

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento, Jacinto!

Comment: @Jacinto e eu a pensar que era por causa do «Auto da barca do inferno».

Comment: @JorgeB. tu conhecias essas dos quintos? Há alguns quintos no Auto da Barca?

Comment: @Jacinto não tenho a certeza se conheço de ouvir aqui ou se é por causa das novelas. Eu só achei que devia vir do Auto, mas nunca associe nada. Foi só mera curiosidade.

Comment: Também encontrei a expressão "quintos infernos" num processo da Inquisição de Lisboa de 1724, usada em ambiente referente a feiticeiras.

Comment: Jorge, isso é muito interessante. Podes dar a referência na tua resposta, com link se estiver disponível online?

Comment: @bfavaretto, encontrei uma discussão das possíveis origens da expressão, com mais duas hipóteses, num artigo de 1931. Acrescentei um resumo, se estiveres interessado.